# How do I permanently change the contents of a div with JavaScript & PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, persistence

Okay. So I don't have any example code to show, but after doing a bit of research and learning the basics of PHP, I think the answer to my question should be pretty simple.

Here is the scenario, as I would like it to be:

On the homepage there will be several team names, with scores next to them. Like "house-points" in Harry Potter.

Below the score is a small text-field. Below that is a submit button.

The user will put a number in the text-field, press submit, and that number will be added to the team's total score.

NOW. I know how to achieve all of that with JavaScript. Easy. What I want to know IS:

How do I make that new number (the new score total) STAY there. I need to permanently alter the HTML when that submit button is pressed.

All I know is that I need to use PHP. I know the basics of PHP, so whatever the answer is, just throw it at me and I'll figure it out.

Comment: Is the value specific to that user, or global for all users?

Comment: You have to store/retrieve the data from somewhere, whether it be a database or file. Might be a good time to lean how to interact with a database using PHP (you can't do this with just javascript, and certainly not just with HTML). SQLite might be a good option for now: http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php Or use MySQL and PDO: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like what you want to do is submitting forms. First drop the JavaScript, you won't need it. What you need is to put your text fields in a form and when you submit you can fetch your values with `$_<GET|POST|REQUEST>['<name_of_field>']`.

Then you will need to store it somehow. The best way to do it is to use a database like MySQL or MongoDB to store it, but it could be a bit tricky if you are just learning this, so maybe you would like to stick to files. You could do this with INI files and PHP's INI functions.

Lastly you will need to print out the correct values to the website. Now this is easy: Just edit your HTML file to do something like

```
<?php echo $score['team1']; ?>
```

for each team after retrieving the correct values at the top or something. (Don't forget to rename the HTML file to .php as well).

Now you should be all set to save your scores. =)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean really permanent you'll have to send it to a database via Ajax (combination of PHP and Javascript). OR write it to a text-document, which is less good.